# Getting rid of spaces in my function without string

Tags: c++

The number value in this project is not showing, the base works fine but I really could use some help figuring out the reason why it is not printing. It gets to the point where it prints out the base but after that it just stops.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <cctype>;
using namespace std;

const int MIN_VALID_BASE = 2;
const int MAX_VALID_BASE = 9;
const int MAX_LENGTH = 256;

//------------------ Function Properties ------------------
int ReadUntilValidBaseRead( );
int ReadNumbersReturningValue( int base );
int DecimalValueOf( char chDigit );
bool IsValid( char chDigit, int base );

int main()
{
   int totalSum = 0;
   int numberValue;
   int base;
   base = ReadUntilValidBaseRead();
   while(!cin.eof())
   {
      cout << "For the given base " << base << ",";
      numberValue = ReadNumbersReturningValue(base);
      if (numberValue == -1)
         cout << " the number is NOT valid!" << endl;
      else
      {
         cout << "the decimal value of the input string is "
            << numberValue << endl;
         totalSum = numberValue + totalSum;
      }
      base = ReadUntilValidBaseRead();

   }
   cout << "The total sum of all valid values is " << totalSum << endl;

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function reads bases until a valid base is read or eof occurs.
// If an invalid base is read, an error message is displayed and the 
// rest of the line is ignored and another attempt to read a base value
// will be attempted.
// -1 is returned if eof occurs otherwise a valid base value is 
// returned.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
int ReadUntilValidBaseRead( )
{
   int baseValid;

      cin >> baseValid;
      while (!cin.eof() && ( baseValid < MIN_VALID_BASE ||
         baseValid > MAX_VALID_BASE))
      {
         cout << "Invalid base given, throwing away the "
            << "rest of the line.";
         cin.ignore(MAX_LENGTH, '\n');
         cin >> baseValid;
      }
      if (baseValid >= MIN_VALID_BASE || baseValid <= MAX_VALID_BASE)
          return baseValid;
      else
          return -1;


}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function reads in a sequence of characters that represent
// a number in the given base.  A valid sequence is given in a 
// "backwards" format such that the rightmost digit is given first,
// the second to the rightmost digit is next, etc. 
// This function returns the value of this sequence of characters if
// it is a valid sequence.  If it is not valid it returns -1. 
// params: TODO
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
int ReadNumbersReturningValue( int base )
{
   int numberValue;
   char chDigit;
   int sum = 0;
   int basePOW = 1;
   bool valid = IsValid(chDigit, base);
   do
   {
      cin >> chDigit;
   }while (isspace(chDigit));
   valid;
   while (valid && chDigit != '\n')
   {
      valid = IsValid(chDigit, base);
      sum += (DecimalValueOf(chDigit) * (basePOW *= base));
      cin >> chDigit;
   }
   if (valid)
      return sum;
   else
      return -1;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function returns the numeric value of the character digit that
// is stored in chDigit.
// params: TODO
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
int DecimalValueOf( char chDigit )
{
   return chDigit - '0';
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function returns true if chDigit is a valid digit in the given
// base, it returns false otherwise.
// params: TODO
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
bool IsValid( char chDigit, int base )
{
   return DecimalValueOf(chDigit) < base &&
        DecimalValueOf(chDigit) >= 0;

}
```

Comment: Get rid of those semicolons after your `#include` statements.

Comment: You should be able to narrow this down by setting some break points and debugging.

Comment: I did that but that isn't what's wrong

Comment: @user2917477 I know. There's a lot more things wrong than that.

Comment: The problem occurs where the numbersare being read in. I know its either in the main where that function is called or its in the actual ReadInNumbers() function.

Comment: I just don't know how to take care of it... any and all help is appreciated

Comment: There are a LOT of things wrong with this code.  Break down your code into smaller pieces testing each piece and then put them together.  As an additional hint:  `while (!cin.eof()...)` is wrong on so many levels.

Comment: This is for my class and my Professor told me this was the way to go. I just need help on getting the numbers to be read in successfully. It works by itself in both the Base function and Number function, but when the two come together it isn't working.

Comment: Check my answer. Once I fixed that error the code runs. Whether or not everything's functioning correctly will be for you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Just by debugging your code, one can notice that you didn't initialize the variable "chDigit". Because of that, the code might break in line 83, where you have this:

```
int ReadNumbersReturningValue( int base )
{
    int numberValue;
    char chDigit; // <------- SHOULDN'T HAVE BEEN INITIALIZED?
    int sum = 0;
    int basePOW = 1;
    bool valid = IsValid(chDigit, base); // <------ HERE
. . .
```

Did you check that? It might be your problem.